# Confusion with Google Cloud Platform and Google Cloud Storage API's

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-api-cpp-client

I am new with google cloud platform and trying to get started. I am interested in using Google Cloud storage.
Following this link:
[datastore reference](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries) I can see available client libraries (c++ is not one of them)

Now there is google api c++ client: 
[google api c++ client](http://google.github.io/google-api-cpp-client/latest/available_service_apis.html)
and it has "Google Cloud Datastore API" as one of the service api's available.

And then there is this link:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/cpp/

which just says:

"The Google APIs C++ Client Library is no longer available. Thank you for your interest."

That got me a bit confused. As I would like to use cloud DataStore via native c++ api.

Comment: You might be able to get help from the support forum (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-api-cpp-client) though it's not an official Google channel.

Comment: Note that Google Cloud Storage is not similar to Google Cloud Datastore: one is a file storage (https://cloud.google.com/storage/) while the other is a NoSQL database (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/)

Comment: @3371862 thanks for pointing out, I meant I want to use DataStore (nosql db) I will change my question

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to do quite a bit of work you can interact with the REST API directly using whatever technology you like.  You'll need to do understand how to generate an OAUTH2 credential and how the OAUTH2 scopes etc. work.  You can then create an OAUTH2 cookie for the Authorization header.  Once you're on top of the that the Google APIs helps you navigate the APIs and work out the expected requests and responses:

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/

The REST guide lets you try out calls yourself too.